# Cant use apt-get upgrade after force quitting software updater

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, dpkg, lock

I was updating the apps and ubuntu via the software updater in my ubuntu 14.04 . But the updater froze and i had to forc quit it . Now i cant update or uninstall any apps or use apt-get upgrade or apt-get update (in apt get update , the error appears in the end of the update ). I get the error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I also get this error when using `sudo apt get upgrade` for the first time:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Comment: Do as it says `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Thank you ,, that didnt work before , now it worked . The problem is fixed.

Comment: No problem.. Do you want me to add an answer so that you can select it as accepted?

Comment: @heemayl .. that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Do a reboot. Then wen started asnew run from terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I ran the code .. sudo apt-get update is working properly until the end where it shows    Fetched 2,622 kB in 56s (46.3 kB/s)                                            
W: Failed to fetch http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
user@user-HP-Notebook:~$

Comment: As @heemayl already said in the comments in the before post run a `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and try again. If this fails aswell then the archive may be down at the moment then continue without it and try a full run of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` later.

Answer (score 0):

try to repair broken packages

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

and if didn't work try

```
sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo fuser -cuk /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help and support . I had previously tried sudo dpkg --configure -a ,, but it gave some result which i could not comprehend . But somehow today , when I ran the same code, it worked . The problem is fixed now .

Comment: It was probably because you did a reboot.